# Application crash in IPhone 6 while reloadData

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm using collection view in side UITableViewCell, on reload

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let _cell = cell as? BrandRow else { return }

        let _flow = columnLayout
        _flow.scrollDirection = .horizontal

        _cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = _flow
        _cell.collectionView.delegate = self
        _cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section
        _cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
        _cell.collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        _cell.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        _cell.collectionView.reloadData()

    }
```

In iPhone 6 while cell get reused it crashes my app

```
_cell.collectionView.reloadData()
```

can anyone please let me know what's wrong with my code?

**Error**

> Assertion failure in -[UICollectionViewData validateLayoutInRect:],
> /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKitCore/UIKit-3698.140/UICollectionViewData.m:447
>
> 2021-01-28 17:10:08.921104+0500 Okayhai[630:48362] *** Terminating app
> due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
> 'UICollectionView received layout attributes for a cell with an index
> path that does not exist: <NSIndexPath: 0xec57a98e0a4dfaae> {length =
> 2, path = 0 - 4}'

Comment: The code that sets the layout, delegate and scroll indicators  should be in another function that is only run once. What is the crash detail/exception message?

Comment: check the error i have mentioned in query.

Comment: `willDisplayCell` is not a good place to be running this code. The one-time setup you should do in an `init` method. The other code should be in your `cellForRowAt`.  Storing indexpath data in `tag` is also best avoided. It can cause problems if your table allows cell reordering or insertion/deletion.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

below `_cell.collectionView.reloadData()`

put

```
_cell.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

Comment: i have already used it but it's not working in my case.